# How to share a link to a YouTube video that autoplays in HD

Tags: youtube, sharing

I've searched around and found some solutions:

- Tried adding parameters like `?hd=1` or `&vq=large` at the end of the
  video and share URL with no success.
- Also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23147137/2313339) which uses the /embed/ URL and adds p.e. `?vq=hd1080;` at the end.

But none of them work in my case, even when some people mention the second works for them. The answer also seems to be from last year, maybe someone has an updated alternative?

I'll prefer a link to the actual YouTube site if possible.

Comment: Not an answer but related: ["Attach parameters to the Youtube iframe URL to modify its behaviour"](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/youtube-api-lightbox2.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

YouTube adjusts the video quality based on a viewer's screen size and connection speed, and they can even adjust the quality while the video is playing if connection speed changes (which actually is quite common; the majority of viewers already is on mobile devices).

Therefore, YouTube believes they know what's best for the viewer and thus don't let you preset or force any specific quality.